# Xcode 12 doesn't support new iOS version

Tags: xcode, xcode12

Trying to build on iPhone, but here's what it shows..

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Download the latest beta of Xcode

Comment: thanks! I had thought that version from AppStore has to be ok.

Comment: App Store version will be released once everything is out of beta. 14.5 and 12.5 are still in release candidate stage.

Comment: Usually you want matching numbers after the `.` (for example, Xcode 12.1 and iOS 14.1, or Xcode 12.5 and iOS 14.5)

Comment: @aheze You are right. Mac App store wasn't showing the available xcode 12.5 update. Upon updating to 12.5 the error is gone!

Comment: Hi! Please consider accepting my answer if it helped. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Sergio , hi! thanks for helping out! What actually helped me was downloading the latest beta of Xcode, so I don't know if this works. No problem to accept if it works for people?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Check out this repo https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport
2. Download this folder:

   [image]
3. Move it into:

   `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`

   [image]
4. Close Xcode and open again.
5. Build and run

Comment: It took me few mins for Xcode to recognize the new folder even after I relaunched few times. Thanks anyway.

Comment: i din't find 14.6

Comment: I'm strongly under the impression Apple forgot to roll out device support for 14.6 and is jumping over to iOS 15 with the XCode 13 beta. Can someone please tell me I'm wrong and it is actually trivial to run an app on a iOS 14.6 real device...

Comment: You can download Xcode 13 beta, go to Applications, right-click on Xcode beta 13, and select Show Package Contents. Once there, go to Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport and look for 14.6. If it exists, it should be there :-)

Answer (score 5):

Just to run the damn thing, I managed to do this without having to download any new profiles as per the other answer. Just took 14.4 renamed to 14.6 and it worked on Catalina XCode 12.4.

Comment: Haha I just changed the folder name of 14.5 to 14.6 and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Where is 14.x ?

Comment: @DougNull /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport as per answer above.

Comment: Folder rename worked for me on Xcode 12.4 and iOS 14.7.1

Answer (score 4):

1. Right-click on /Applications/Xcode & choose **Show Package Contents**
2. Make a duplicate of 14.5 directory by copy and pasting it into the same directory (into DeviceSupport) then rename the directory to 14.6
3. Now Quite Xcode and try again.

It will work 100% sure.

Comment: Show Package Contents doesn't show 14.x on my macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: This is good advice but incomplete.  As Sergio said above, once you Show Package Contents, you have to drill down several directories to find the 14.5 directory.  Specifically: Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/14.5.